# How to set a column equal to the Primary key?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

How can I get the primary key value and put it in another column when I insert the data?

Here is my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [MyTable] (
  [ID] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  [custom_ID] INTEGER NULL, 
  [Name] VARCHAR (200) NULL)
```

The query I have so far is:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (custom_ID, Name)
values (
  ' {Here I need to get the primary key value, and then put it in custom_ID} ', 
  'someName')
```

Thanks!

Comment: Whyever would you want merely to duplicate the `ID` column into the `custom_ID` column?  Seems completely superfluous to me.  Also, why is this question tagged [tag:mysql]?

Comment: The simple way would be to just use an `after insert` `trigger` on MyTable that copies the ID column to the custom_id column.  However, as eggyal asked: Why would you do this?

Answer (score 2):

Don't do that.  You are violating all sorts of good database design principles by going this route.  The primary key is supposed to represent the data that unique identifies a tuple (row).  When you start having multiple copies of your primary key, you in turn defeat the entire purpose of the key.

Comment: what if he wants to generate a custom id for stuufs like billing or invoce or anything, in different format like INV/2013/0001

Comment: @AmitRanjan This is always a huge problem, people design databases to meet their applications.  The relational model and the way you store data has NOTHING to do with an application.

Comment: But what if I want to anyways?  For example, what if I have a user-defined "barcode" column that, if they have not chosen a code value, I default to the PK because it's a convenient and unique number?  Obviously the PK provides a good default for a unique value.  Then the user can change it freely later, while the PK remains its original.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
insert [Order] (col1, col2, ...) values ('val1', 'val2', ...) -- Note: no ID is specified
declare @id int = scope_identity()
insert OrderDetail (order_id, col1, ...) values (@id, 'val1', ...)
```

Comment: I have no idea of what are you talking about... I just gave an idea of how to achive the result.

Comment: Take a look at question tags: one of them is [tag:sqlite]. Code you wrote is probably [tag:TSQL], with unsupported features in SQLite.

Comment: I just aswered to a question which was not specifing any sqlite.  Also, if you can read english i said "try something like this" = an idea but not the actually solution to the the original code.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Chris:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTable_CustomID AFTER INSERT ON MyTable WHEN NEW.Custom_ID=NULL BEGIN
    UPDATE MyTable SET Custom_ID=NEW.Id WHERE ROWID=NEW.ROWID;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far I can say you are trying to generate some custom Id based upon the `PK`. Like if my `PK = 1` then you need a custom Id as `ABCDEF/000/1` . So in that case you have to pick the immediate `Id` generate by the insert query and then run a update statement either in a trigger or just after the insert statement. Since its sql lite so you need to research a little bit to get identity similar to Scope_Identity() or @@Identity in Sql Server.